# Days between dates will not compile

Tags: c, date, calculator

I have been trying to get this to work. I need to input 2 dates (MM DD) and then have the program tell me the amount of days between the 2 dates. But for some reason when i try to use month 2 (February) I dont think its registering that I indicated it having only 28 days. Also when i enter the same date i cant get it to say "0". Please help thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//constructs dates for calculation
struct date{
    int month;
    int day;
};//end date

int main()
{
    struct date first, second; //creates 2 dates to calculate
    int finalDays = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int valid=0;

    printf("Enter first date \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &first.month, &first.day); //user input: first date
    if (first.month == 1||3||5||7||8||10){
       if(first.day > 31){
        printf("Invalid Day\n");
        valid += 1;
       }
    }
    else if (first.month == 4||6||9||11 ){
        if (first.day > 30){
         printf("Invalid Day\n");
         valid += 1;
        }
    }
    else if (first.month == 2){
        if(first.day > 28){
         printf("Invalid Day");
         valid += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter second date\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &second.month, &second.day); // user input: second date
    if (second.month == 1||3||5||7||8||10){
       if(second.day > 31){
        printf("Invalid Day\n");
        valid += 1;
       }
    }
    else if (second.month == 4||6||9||11 ){
        if (second.day > 30){
         printf("Invalid Day\n");
         valid += 1;
        }
    }
    else if (second.month ==2){
        if(second.day > 28){
         printf("Invalid Day");
         valid += 1;
        }
    }

    if (first.month == second.month && first.day == second.day){
        printf("Days between dates: 0");
        valid += 1;
    }

    //Prints statement if month is invalid
    if(first.month > 12 || second.month > 12 || first.month<1 || second.month<1){
        printf("Invalid Date: Invalid month");
    }

    //Prints statement if second date precedes first
    if(second.month<first.month){
        printf("Invalid. Second date cannot precede first date.");
    }
    if (second.month==first.month && second.day<first.day){
        printf("Invalid. Second date cannot precede first date.");
    }

    if(first.month==second.month){
        finalDays = (second.day - first.day);
        printf("Days between dates: %d", finalDays);
        valid+=1;
    }

    if(first.month == 1||3||5||7||8||10||12)         // Days remaining in first month
        total = 31 - first.day;
    else if(first.month == 4||6||9||11)
        total = 30 - first.day;
    else if(first.month == 2)
        total = 28 - first.day;

    for(i = first.month + 1; i < second.month; i++)
    {
      if(i == 3||5||7||8||10||12)
          total += 31;
      else if(i == 4||6||9||11)
          total += 30;
    }
    total += second.day;

    if(valid == 0){
    printf("First date: %d %d \n", first.month, first.day);
    printf("Second date: %d %d \n", second.month, second.day);
    printf("Days between dates: %d", total);
    }

    return 0;
} //end main
```

Comment: `first.month == 1||3||5||7||8||10` is the same as `(first.month == 1) || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10` or the same as `1`

Comment: Pick a good C book and see how expressions work in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (first.month == 1||3||5||7||8||10){
```

This won't do what you want it to do.  It will be evaluated as (first.month == 1)||3||5||7||8||10, which will evaluate to true for all non-zero months.

This would be better written as a case statement;

```
switch (first.month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
        /* Handle 31 day months */
        ...
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        /* Handle 30 day months */
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        /* Handle February */
        ...
        break;
    default:
        /* Handle invalid month */
        break;
}
```

Comment: I should mention that to do what you want with an if statment you need to be way more verbose; e.g. `if (first.month == 4 || first.month==6 || first.month==9 || first.month==10)`